# AnHarmonic oscillator for pendulum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

The ODE for ‘‘small angles’’ of a pendulum is given by $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{l}\theta=0$. Without small angle approximations the right ODE is:

> $$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{l}\sin{\theta}=0 \tag{1}$$

Is there a closed form of $\theta(t)$ for $(1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but only in terms of special functions; see Equation (31) of [this](http://www.sbfisica.org.br/rbef/pdf/070707.pdf) paper, given as

$$ \theta(t) = 2\arcsin\left\{\sin\frac{\theta_{0}}{2}\,\operatorname{sn}\left[K\left(\sin^{2}\frac{\theta_{0}}{2}\right) - \omega_{0}t;\,\sin^{2}\frac{\theta_{0}}{2}\right]\right\}$$

where $\theta_{0}$ is the initial angle, $\omega_{0} = \sqrt{g/l}$, $K$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind, and $\operatorname{sn}$ is a [Jacobi elliptic function.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html)